# What is the Dart null checking idiom or best practice?

Tags: dart

I have the following form of assignment & null checks to avoid double lookups in my maps.
Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this in Dart?

```dart
bool isConnected(a, b){
  List list;
  return (
    ((list = outgoing[a]) != null && list.contains(b)) ||
    ((list = incoming[a]) != null && list.contains(b))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

As of Dart 1.12 null-aware operators are available for this type of situation:

```dart
bool isConnected(a, b) {
  bool outConn = outgoing[a]?.contains(b) ?? false;
  bool inConn = incoming[a]?.contains(b) ?? false;
  return outConn || inConn;
}
```

The `?.` operator short-circuits to null if the left-hand side is null, and the `??` operator returns the left-hand side if it is not null, and the right-hand side otherwise.

The statement

```dart
outgoing[a]?.contains(b)
```

will thus either evaluate to `null` if  `outgoing[a]` is `null`, or the boolean result of `contains(b)` if it is not.

That means the resulting statement will be one of the following:

```
bool outConn = null ?? false; // false
bool outConn = false ?? false; // false
bool outConn = true ?? false; // true
```

The same applies to the `inConn` boolean, which means both `inConn` and `outConn` are guaranteed to be non-null, allowing us to return the result of `||`ing the two.

Comment: Writing `outgoing[a]?.contains(b)` is dangerous, at least with Groovy semantics, because when `outgoing` is `null`, the entire expression evaluates to `null`. So you might in fact get get something like `return (null || true)`, which will throw in checked mode.

Comment: Thanks for the open issue link.

Comment: @Ladicek Thanks for pointing that out. I've incorporated the null-coalescing operator (`??`) into my updated answer to account for that issue.

Comment: Finally landed \o/ https://github.com/gbracha/nullAwareOperators/blob/master/proposal.md

Comment: To check Fields of Objects just write `object?.field ?? true`. Where true can be anything you want.

Comment: Anyone looking for null aware function call ? See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141239/6665568

Comment: Please note that this code is not equivalent to the code in the question. Even when `outConn` evaluates to `true`, `inConn` is evaluated as well; this might have performance implications (from negligible to serious, depending on the situation), or might generally speaking give different behavior (if the called function would have side effects).

Comment: if `contains(b)` returns a void then it will not return null; it simply won't execute.  (and if you set the result to a variable you won't receive a null but receive an error)

Answer (score 131):

#### ??     provides a default if the subject is null

```
return subject ?? "defaultIfNull";
```

#### ??=     sets the subject to a default only if the subject is null

This is similar to ?? but sets the subject variable to a default if it is null.

```
subject ??= "defaultIfNull";
```

#### ?.     avoid an exception, return null or don't execute function/method if the object on the left is null

`object?.x` will return null if object is null, `object.x` would cause an exception if object were null

This can also be used when calling methods.  For example

for void methods, `object?.myVoidMethod()` - if `object` is null then `myVoidMethod` will not execute.

and for methods that return values `object?.returnValueMethod()` - if `object` is null then `returnValueMethod` will a return null.

It can also be used with function calls too with the `call` operator.  For example `myCallbackFunction?.call()` will only execute if myFunction is not null.

#### ...?     from a spread collection, avoid a null item in the final list if the subject list is null

the result of the following

```
[
  ...[1, 2],
  null,
]
```

is `[1, 2, null]`

to avoid the null value use ...?

```
var resultingList = [
  ...[1, 2],
  ...?subjectList,
];
```

#### ?     for lists & maps

the result of the following

```
List<String>? myNullableList = null;
myNullableList?[1] ?? ["my", "default", "entries"];
```

is

```
["my", "default", "entries"]
```

#### !.     Null assertion operator

Casts an expression to its underlying non-nullable type, throwing a runtime exception if the cast fails

Comment: Important remark about using __?.__: if nullable reference `a` has void method `method()`, the following syntax `a?.method();` will execute method only if `a` is not null.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk, great point! but is there any way to do something like this>>> if a is not null... then execute a method XYZ(),when this method is not a member of the object a's class???

Comment: @YoApps Did I get this clear that you want to execute a method which is not a part of class signature? It is not possible to do in any OOP language I'm aware of.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk yeah I tried it too, didnt work so reverted back to the old `if(a!=null){XYZ();}`

Comment: @YoApps. Oh, you mean this code. No, it is not possible in Dart.

Comment: @YoApps you can do `if (a != null) { XYZ(); }` in Dart. It's not a one-liner, though. Python has an if expression, enabling you to write something like `XYZ() if condition else ABC()`.

Comment: what about `!.` ?

Comment: @KristiJorgji I'd say it doesn't apply as it doesn't check for a null.  Its more of a type conversion from an `int?` to an `int`

Comment: update with `!.` operator!

Answer (score 19):

Posting the following, as I ended up here by searching the title.

As per https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/66, it seems that the answer to "What is the Dart null checking idiom or best practice?" is:

There is no null checking idiom or best practice in the general case. If null-aware operators don't fit your case use direct comparison as in `if (object == null)` or `if (object != null)`.

Comment: they have optionals now :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool ok<T>(T obj) => obj != null;
bool nul<T>(T obj) => obj == null;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the OPs question, but it is what I was looking for and what lead me here.

I want to convert null values to blank strings - to safely process stuff.

I now use this:

```dart
String ifNullThenBlank(String? val) => ((val==null) ? '' : val);
```

In fact, I even have this single line of code in `if_null_than_blank.dart`.

It's dumb, but I haven't found better.

Comment: `y = ifNullThenBlank(x)` is equivalent to `y = x ?? ''`;