# Null aware function invocation operator

Tags: dart, nullable

In the same way we can have

```dart
nullableClassInstance?.method(blah)
```

Is there a way to do

```dart
nullableFunctionInstance?(blah)
```

In other words, is there an operator that checks whether a function instance is not `null`, if so, invoke the function all in one line?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141239/6665568

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Using the [`call` method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Function-class.html), you can achieve what you want with:

```dart
nullableFunctionInstance?.call(blah)
```

There's also the [`apply` method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Function/apply.html) if you want to pass arguments.

Comment: But I have to wrap my function in a callable class or am I misunderstanding this? Invoking "call" or "apply" on a variable of type e.g. 'void Function(int)' throws a compiler error

Answer (score 19):

If you have a Function Object , you can use the `call` method and send all the parameters to that which works exactly as calling the function. Here , you can use the null aware member access operator.

```
void myFun(int a , int b){...}

var myVar = myFun ;
```

## call

The function myVar will only get called if its not null as shown below.

```
myVar?.call( arg1 , arg2 );
```

### apply

If your function is dynamic or you wish to control which function is being called at run time , you can use the `apply` static method of `Function` like so :

```
Function.apply(myVar , [arg1 , arg2]);
```

`apply` takes the function and a `List` of parameters that will be sent to the function.

Read more about [call](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Function-class.html) and [apply](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Function/apply.html) :