# Null-aware function call?

Tags: dart, dart-2

Dart has some null-aware operators, i.e. it is possible to do

```
var obj;
obj?.foo(); // foo is only called if obj != null.
```

Is this also possible for functions that are stored or passed to variables? The usual pattern is

```
typedef void SomeFunc();

void foo(SomeFunc f) {
  if (f != null) f();
}
```

It would be nice to have some null-aware calling here, like `f?()`. Is there anything we can use to not litter the code with null checks for those callbacks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Form the [docs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> Dart is a true object-oriented language, so even functions are objects and have a type, Function.

Apply the null aware `?.` operator to the `call` method of function objects:

```
typedef void SomeFunc();

SomeFunc f = null;

f?.call();
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed works. From the docs alone, this wasn't clear to me (the "call()" is mentioned only for callable classes. But put together, it makes sense.

Comment: You can also use `apply` for this for more control : See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141239/6665568