# How to safely call (with null check) a variable of type Function

Tags: dart

Is there an easy way to invoke the function with null check ?

```
Function(String) onTextReady;
```

Is there an easy way to safely invoke this function.
In Kotlin for example I would use invoke:

```
onTextReady?.invoke('Hello world');
```

I tried `onTextReady?.('Hello world');` but Dart doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, short answer, no (with the operator). The null-aware `?.` operator in Dart will work only with object call to members, not to null-check a function execution directly.

In this case bellow, it would work:

```dart
class MyClass {
  Function(String s) onTextReady = (s) => print(s);
}

main() {
  var nullObject;
  nullObject?.onTextReady('null'); // do nothing

  var notNull = MyClass();
  notNull?.onTextReady('not null'); // print 'not null'
}
```

You would need to check it manually (!= null) to be null-safe:

```dart
main() {
  Function(String) onTextReady;

  if(onTextReady != null) {
    onTextReady('null');
  }

  Function(String) onTextReady2 = (s) => print(s);

  if(onTextReady2 != null) {
    onTextReady2('not null');
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the example but usually `clazz` is used to name variables which hold a reference to the class, in your case you are using it to name an object which is confusing.

Comment: This answer worked awesome for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141239/6665568