# Shorthand for calling a nullable callback in Dart?

Tags: dart

Say, I have this:

```
VoidCallback callback;
```

It can only be called if it isn't null, so for that I am doing:

```
if (callback != null) callback();
```

Is there any shorthand similar to this?

```
callback?.();
```

Comment: Your question title is wrong. You mean calling a *nullable* *callback*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null aware function invocation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022232/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin), the solution is:

```
VoidCallback callback;
callback?.call();
```