# Flutter. Dart. Null-aware callback call?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, null

If we have an object...

```
obj?.foo(); // foo is only called if obj != null.
```

What is the modern style of writing for this?

```
if (onError != null) onError!();
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Both should work...

Comment: @nvoigt They're referring to an anonymous function assigned to a variable called `onError`. They don't want the if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null aware function invocation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022232/null-aware-function-invocation-operator)