# How to call provider on condition?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

On app homepage I set up `Model2` which make API call for data. User can then navigate to other page (`Navigator.push`). But I want make API call from `Model2` when user press back (`_onBackPress()`) so can refresh data on homepage.

Issue is Model2 is not initialise for all user. But if I call `final model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);` for user where Model2 is not initialise, this will give error.

How I can call Provider only on condition? For example: `if(user == paid)`

`StatefulWidget` in homepage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>

...
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(context: context)),
```

In Page2:

```
Future<void> _onBackPress(context) async {

// if(user == paid)
final model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);

  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return 

// if(user == paid)
    Provider.value(value: model2, child:


AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Back'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Go back'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () async {

// if(user == paid)
await model2.getData();

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Alternative method (maybe more easy): How to call provider on previous page (homepage) on `Navigator.of(context).pop();`?

TLDR: What is best solution for call API so can refresh data when user go back to previous page (but only for some user)?

Comment: `Model2 is not initialise for all user.` What does this means?

Comment: @RémiRousselet This mean I only use `Model2` on homepage for some user. Other user see different homepage and I not set up `Model2` with for that page –

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your second page interface builder in a `WillPopScope` widget, and then, pass whatever method you want to call to the `onWillPop` callback of the `WillPopScope` widget. This way, you can make your API call when user presses the back button. Find more about the `WillPopScope` widget on [this WillPopScope Flutter dev documentation article](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html).

Comment: This not answer question. Even in `WillPopScope` I must segment users and call from `provider`

Answer (score 0):

> **tldr;** Establish and check your single point of truth before the call to the Provider
>   that may result in a null value or evaluate as a nullable reference.

Perhaps you can change the architecture a bit to establish a single (nullable or bool) reference indicating whether the user has paid. Then use Darts nullability checks (or just a bool) to implement the behavior you want. This differs from your current proposal in that there would be no need to call on the Provider to instantiate the model. Just add a single point of truth to your User object that is initialized to null or false, and then change that logic only when the User has actually paid.

Toggling widgets/behavior in this way could be a solution.

Alternatives considered:

- Packaging critical data points into a separate library so that the values can be imported where needed.
- Other state management methods for key/value use.
- If you want to simply hide/show parts of a page consider using the [OffStage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) class or the [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) class

Ref
[Dart null-checking samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006664/what-is-the-dart-null-checking-idiom-or-best-practice)