# How to loop through an array of variables in Dart

Tags: dart

```
String A = null;
String B = null;
var C = List<someObject>();
...
```

Instead of checking writing code to check each parameter individually, wonder if we could put all those parameters in an array and loop thru to check for not null and not empty? Thanks

Comment: You definitely can. What do you want to *do* if the values are null or empty? You have the issue that `String` and `List` have no common superclass which exposes `isEmpty`, so you will have to either recognize each type that you care about, or perform optimistic dynamic invocations of `object.isEmpty` without any type-checking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class SomeObject {}

void main() {
  String A = null;
  String B = null;
  var C = List<SomeObject>();

  if ([A, B, C].anyNull()) {
    throw "ARGHHHHH";
  }
}

extension AnyNullExtension on List {
  bool anyNull() => this.any((Object e) => e == null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple for-loop like other programming languages.

```
for (var i=0; i<C.length; i++) {
   var notNull = C[i] ?? "someThingElse"
}
```

[??](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) is one of the null-aware operators provided by Dart

Answer (score 0):

Here an example code: (you can check it on dartpad.dev)

```
void main() {
  String A = null;
  String B = null;
  String D = "a real string";
  var C = List<String>();
  List<String> E = ["one", "two"];

  List items = [A, B, C, D, E];

  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var no = i + 1;

    if(item == null) {
      print("item " + no.toString() + " is null");
    }
    else if(item?.isEmpty ?? true) {
      print("item " + no.toString() + " is empty");
    }

    print("Item " + no.toString() + " is \"" + item.toString() + "\"");
  }
}
```

So, first you create a List with all the items. Then with a for-loop (foreach doesn't work with different types) you check each item.
To understand the ?. and the ?? checkout answer below, is well explained there ;)
Instead of print you could do a different thing like break or throw an error.

Checkout this answer too, it doens't directly answer your question, but probably avoids it :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006968