# Prefer using if null operators

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart suggest me to use `if null operator` . Why ? and how to use it?

This is my code:

```
var name;
name != null ? name : 'nobody';
```

Comment: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006664/what-is-the-dart-null-checking-idiom-or-best-practice*

Answer (score 4):

In other languages we can use the logical-or shortcut. If maybeSomeNumber() returns null, assign a default value of 2:

```
value = maybeSomeNumber() || 2
```

In Dart we can't do this because the expression needs to be a boolean (“the operands of the || operator must be assignable to bool”).

That's why the ?? operator exists:

```
var value = maybeSomeNumber() ?? 2;
```

Similarly, if we wanted to ensure a value argument was not-null we'd do:

```
value = value ?? 2;
```

But there's an even simpler way.
Fallback assignment operator: ??=

```
value ??= 2;
```

check the original artical: https://flutterigniter.com/checking-null-aware-operators-dart/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we need to use conditions or ternary operator here. It will increase program complexity. Try below

```
name = name || 'nobody';
```

Comment: This does not work in dart. (linter error : The operands of the operator '||' must be assignable to 'bool')