# my code not complete for where contact number

Tags: flutter, service, contacts, dart-null-safety

How to fix code my code flutter and use plugin

```dart
     filterContacts() {
        setState(() {
          List<Contact> _contacts = [];
              _contacts.addAll(contacts);
          if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
            _contacts.retainWhere(
              (contact) {
                String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase().trim();
                String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
                String contactName = contact.displayName.toString().toLowerCase();
                bool nameMatches = contactName.contains(searchTerm);
                if (nameMatches == true) {
                  return true;
                }
                if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
                  return false;
                }
    
                var phone = contact.phones.firstWhere((phn) {
                  String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn);
                  return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
                }, orElse: () => null);
    
                return phone != null;
              },
            );
                contactsFiltered = _contacts;
          }
        });
      }
```

Flutter code How to fix code my code flutter and use plugin [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service),
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uih2D.jpg) image is about a problem

Answer (score 0):

`contact.phones` can be null, in this you need to check its value 1st then proceed,

you can use  `contact.phones?.firstWhere` to handle this situation or

If you're sure it will have value, you can also do `contact.phones!.firstWhere` but I don't recommend this. You don't need to use `orElse` you want to pass null,

```dart
   Item? phone = contact.phones?.firstWhere((phn) {
              String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn);
              return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
            },  );
```

You can learn more about [`?.` `!`...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17006664/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

[how to fix now]
[error code not complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9d8f.jpg)

```dart
  filterContacts() {
    setState(() {
      List<Contact> _contacts = [];

      _contacts.addAll(contacts);
      if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        _contacts.retainWhere(
          (contact) {
            String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase().trim();
            String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
            String contactName = contact.displayName.toString().toLowerCase();
            bool nameMatches = contactName.contains(searchTerm);
            if (nameMatches == true) {
              return true;
            }

            if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
              return false;
            }

            Item? phone = contact.phones?.firstWhere((phn) {
              String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(phn);
              return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
            }, );

            return phone != null;
          },
        );

        contactsFiltered = _contacts;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are there any changes beside  my answer ? you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)